# Decreasing space between title and body in scrartcl

Tags: spacing, koma-script, article

Here is a MWE using `scrartcl`. If I just have a title, and no subtitle, author,
date, or any of that other stuff, is there a clean way I can decrease the space between the title and the body, here denoted by a section header?

The `maketitle` command in `scrartcl.cls` seems to be very complex. I also noticed that `scrlttr2` has a lot of adjustable length parameters called pseudo-lengths which is helpful, but the other classes don't have them. I wonder why.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\areaset{16.5cm}{31.0cm}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\title{Here is A Title}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Summary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `scrartcl` class adds a wealth of vertical spaces:

- `2em` at the top
- `\topsep` due to `\begin{center}`
- `1.5em` after the “subject”, if given
- `.5em` after the title
- `1em` after the subtitle, present or not
- at least `\baselineskip+.5em` for the author, present or not
- `1em` after the author, present or not
- `0pt plus 1em` after the date, empty or not
- `\topsep` due to `\end{center}`
- a final `2em`

In your case, `\baselineskip` is 13.6pt, 1em is 11pt and `\topsep` is 9.0pt plus 3.0pt minus 5.0pt. So after the title you have a vertical space of

```
5.5 + 11 + 13.6 + 5.5 + 11 + 9 + 22 = 77.6
```

points, that is more than five and a half full lines.

To that you have to add the space left before a section title (since `\maketitle` uses `\vskip`, the `\addvspace` in front of section titles can't realize there's no space to add.

If I try

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\areaset{16.5cm}{31.0cm}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\title{Here is A Title}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-77.6pt}

some text to show the real space

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

{\centering\sffamily\bfseries\huge Here is A Title\par}

some text to show the real space

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

You can notice that there's some more space that I probably lost somewhere.

How to remedy to this situation? Asking Markus Kohm to write a better `\@maketitle` macro.